# Constrained imputation in Python

Tags: python, optimization, data-imputation, constrained-optimization

I actually have two original datasets (each one for a departure that are related to each one in a specific way , but it's not important to know how exactly) , but these 2 datasets contain some outliers in the column 'value' that i deleted and which led to the creation of 2 new datasets filtered. My main objective is to actually impute the deleted values but additionally i want the imputed values to respect a certain constraint which is that the relative difference between "The sum of original values of both departures" ( Y1 +Y2) and "The sum of imputed values of both departures" ( X1+X2) must be inferior to a certain threshold ( percentage epsilon).I Initialized the values with a KNN method.
This is what i wrote for my code

```
# fonction huber loss
def huber_loss(x, y, eps):
    diff = np.abs(y - x)
    bool = diff <= eps
    loss = 0.5 * (diff**2) * bool + eps * (diff - 0.5 * eps) * (1 - bool)
    return np.sum(loss)

# fonction objective
def objective(x1, x2, y1, y2, eps, lam):
    mse = np.mean((y2 +y1 - x2 - x1)**2)
    
    constraint_loss = huber_loss(x1 + x2, y1 + y2, eps)
    return  mse + lam*constraint_loss

# fonction pour imputation avec contrainte pour les deux départs
def constrained_imputation(data1=pd.DataFrame, data2=pd.DataFrame,df1=pd.DataFrame,df2=pd.DataFrame, eps=400, lam=0.7, max_iter=10000, tol=1e-9, alpha=0):
    # on repere les indices des valeurs manquantes
    value_missing=data1['value'].isnull()
    indexes_missing = np.where(value_missing)[0]
    #on récupère les valeurs réelles sur les périodes de reports de charge 
    y1=df1['value'][indexes_missing].values
    y2=df2['value'][indexes_missing].values 
    # knn imputation sur les deux départs pour initialiser
    imputer1 = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
    X=data1.drop(['horodate','gdo','Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)
    x01 = imputer1.fit_transform(X)
    x01=x01[:,0]
    x01=x01[indexes_missing]

    imputer2 = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
    X=data2.drop(['horodate','gdo','Unnamed: 0'],axis=1)
    x02 = imputer2.fit_transform(X)
    x02=x02[:,0]
    x02=x02[indexes_missing]
    # Définit la fonction d'optimization :
    fun = lambda x: objective(x[:len(indexes_missing)], x[len(indexes_missing):], y1, y2, eps, lam)
    # Le vecteur x0 pour lequel il faut trouver la solution :
    x0 = np.concatenate([x01, x02])
    # Minimization de la fonction objective 
    result = minimize(fun, x0, method='L-BFGS-B', options={'maxiter': max_iter, 'ftol': tol})
    # on extrait les valeurs imputées :
    x1_imputed = result.x[:len(indexes_missing)]
    x2_imputed = result.x[len(indexes_missing):]
    #creer les tables finales :
    df_imputed_1,df_imputed_2=data1.copy(),data2.copy()
    df_imputed_1['value'][indexes_missing]=x1_imputed
    df_imputed_2['value'][indexes_missing]=x2_imputed

    return df_imputed_1,df_imputed_2
```

But i feel like even when i tune the values of the parameters of the function it doesn't really change the number of imputed values that verify the constraint. I think that the problem might be caused by the objective function , so what do u guys think about this ? What are the objective functions possible that i can use in this problem , or if there is another possible method to impute with a specific constraint.